In MicroROS/Agent Is there a message size limit when both the Pub/Sub are MicroROS node
Note: This is a repost from the Slack channel
I am trying to  send a CompressedImage type from a camera node to an LCD Node and it appears that I am sending messages, but the callback on the Subscriber node is not being called.

The project is using the latest ROS Humble (MicroROS + Agent)
The image size is between 7-11K (QVGA) and I have the MTU set to 10K
The message rate has been varied between 1 frame every 2 seconds (.5
Hz rate)  to  5 frames/second (5 Hz rate) The Agent is configured for
UDP4/port 8888 and I have pulled a fresh docker image.
Pub/Sub uses init_default() which results in a RELIABLE transport
The Camera node reports that it is sending images, and I can see an message rate in
the TopicMonitor.
I can capture messages in a ROSBag.
I have also verified that the QoS profiles match between pub/sub(s).
In wireshark, I can see UDP messages between the camera node and the
Agent, but no messages Agent to LCD Node.

The one thing that made a difference, was to send a fake message using only the first 20 bytes of the Image. When I do this, the Subscriber callback is called. Only the image size was modified, the rest of the configuration/code remained the same
i.e. On the publisher, I fixed the data.len to 20 bytes and only memcpy the first 20bytes of the image
I looked through the Agent code, but nothing seems obvious about limiting message size.
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you
John
